# error when installing packages in R or RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, install.packages

I recently installed R and Rstudio in my Mac computer (both are the latest version). But I had below error when I try to install packages.

I tried to install packages in both R and RStudio, from both command line and from "install package" menu, none of those works.

I also tried use options(repos = c(CRAN = "URL")) with different URLs, but still get the same error.

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[R.app GUI 1.70 (7521) x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0]

> a <- available.packages()
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv'); using local file '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'

Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'

> install.packages('ggplot2', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
> options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
> install.packages('ggplot2')
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5:
cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
> options(repos = c(CRAN = "http://cloud.r-project.org/"))
> install.packages('ggplot2')
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
cannot open URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5:
cannot open URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
>
```

Your help will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on a Virtual machine or a server ? It seems that R can't connect to the internet. What happens when you do : `readLines("http://google.com")` ?

Comment: I'm running it from my laptop, not virtual machine or server. Just tried your readLines comment, it gives me the same error says: cannot open the connection to 'http://google.com". but I do have internet access because I can access URLs from browser, for example: URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'. is there something wrong with my setting?

Comment: I get this result:

`> options(internet.info = 0)
> install.packages("dplyr")
Error in install.packages : error reading from connection
> readLines("http://google.com")
* Rebuilt URL to: http://google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.17.110...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2a00:1450:400e:809::200e...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2a00:1450:400e:809::200e: No route to host
*   Trying 2a00:1450:400e:809::200e...`